# Spring Boot 3 fails to generate native image when having Avro as a dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm running `./gradlew nativeCompile` to generate a native image on a project that has `implementation("org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.1")` as a dependency, with the following exception:

```
2022-12-19T12:29:21.693+01:00  INFO [metrics,,] 81039 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Pre-creating binder child context (AOT) for kstream
2022-12-19T12:29:21.695+01:00  INFO [metrics,,] 81039 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Pre-creating binder child context (AOT) for ktable
2022-12-19T12:29:21.696+01:00  INFO [metrics,,] 81039 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Pre-creating binder child context (AOT) for globalktable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getCanonicalName()" is null
        at org.springframework.aot.hint.BindingReflectionHintsRegistrar.shouldSkipMembers(BindingReflectionHintsRegistrar.java:75)
        at org.springframework.aot.hint.BindingReflectionHintsRegistrar.lambda$registerReflectionHints$0(BindingReflectionHintsRegistrar.java:88)
        at org.springframework.aot.hint.ReflectionHints.registerType(ReflectionHints.java:86)
        at org.springframework.aot.hint.ReflectionHints.registerType(ReflectionHints.java:109)
        at org.springframework.aot.hint.BindingReflectionHintsRegistrar.registerReflectionHints(BindingReflectionHintsRegistrar.java:87)
        at org.springframework.aot.hint.BindingReflectionHintsRegistrar.registerReflectionHints(BindingReflectionHintsRegistrar.java:65)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeContributor.contribute(TypeContributor.java:70)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeContributor.contribute(TypeContributor.java:82)
        at org.springframework.data.aot.ManagedTypesBeanRegistrationAotProcessor.contributeType(ManagedTypesBeanRegistrationAotProcessor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.aot.MongoManagedTypesBeanRegistrationAotProcessor.contributeType(MongoManagedTypesBeanRegistrationAotProcessor.java:53)
        at org.springframework.data.aot.ManagedTypesRegistrationAotContribution.lambda$applyTo$0(ManagedTypesRegistrationAotContribution.java:97)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeCollector.processType(TypeCollector.java:104)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeCollector.processType(TypeCollector.java:118)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeCollector.processType(TypeCollector.java:118)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeCollector.processType(TypeCollector.java:118)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeCollector.processType(TypeCollector.java:118)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeCollector.processType(TypeCollector.java:118)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeCollector.process(TypeCollector.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeCollector$ReachableTypes.lambda$forEach$0(TypeCollector.java:217)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeCollector$ReachableTypes.forEach(TypeCollector.java:217)
        at org.springframework.data.aot.ManagedTypesRegistrationAotContribution.applyTo(ManagedTypesRegistrationAotContribution.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.lambda$generateBeanDefinitionMethod$2(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:179)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.generateBeanDefinitionMethod(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.generateBeanDefinitionMethod(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.lambda$generateRegisterBeanDefinitionsMethod$2(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:85)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.generateRegisterBeanDefinitionsMethod(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:83)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.lambda$applyTo$1(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:67)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethod.<init>(GeneratedMethod.java:54)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:112)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.applyTo(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:66)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.applyTo(BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.java:78)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.lambda$processAheadOfTime$0(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:58)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.withCglibClassHandler(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:67)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.processAheadOfTime(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:53)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.performAotProcessing(ContextAotProcessor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:76)

> Task :processAot FAILED
```

The exception happens in `BindingReflectionHintsRegistrar.shouldSkipMembers(...)`--> `type.getCanonicalName()`:

```
    private boolean shouldSkipMembers(Class<?> type) {
        return type.getCanonicalName().startsWith("java.") || type.isArray();
    }
```

The type that generates the NullPointer is `class org.apache.avro.JsonProperties$1`.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: So a class says its name is null. Hmm. Anyway, it mentions reflection, so it might be just some reflective access that isn't configured. You might want to run your app with agent enabled and see if it generates any reflection config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular `NullPointerException` [has been solved in this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29657), the fix has been released with Spring Framework 6.0.3.